# Can I Hook Up A Infected Drive To Another Computer?

Tags: virus, hard-drive

I have an old computer that has old games on it and has some kind of virus or such. If I hooked up its drive, would I be able to copy the files over to my laptop, or would even connecting the drive trigger a virus?

Comment: It depends on the kind of infection you have.

Comment: Just connecting a drive and therefore making a number of files available won't be an issue as there is nothing "active".  It might be worth running a scan over the files you move to your laptop to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

> would I be able to copy the files over to my laptop

If you are sure the disk is infected with virus, better scan the files and copy file only when it comes clean. Malware hiding frameworks and other similar tech(crypters, packers, encoders, binders, obfuscators or mix & match of similar tech) does a fairly good job of hiding the virus. Its always better to scan with multiple scanners to be sure of the file being free from any virus(malware). I suggest you give a try virus-total though many virus(malware) will not be detected by virus-total right away but it doesn't hurt to try the best possible way to avoid files which may detect infectious.

> or would even connecting the drive trigger a virus?

It depends upon the nature of virus. Kindly consider taking calculated risk only if absolutely necessary, by studying the characteristics/specifics of virus detected.